# react sends an axios post request in the form-data form, the problem is 500 error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, postman, form-data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ9lk.png)
I send a post request from postman as follows, it will be posted well. However,  write the react code as follows, the server is not receiving data with 500 errors. Is it a problem with my code or the server?

```
  const postChallenge = async () => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      const newData = {
        title: 'title',
        content: 'contents',
      };
      formData.append('requestBody', JSON.stringify(newData));
      formData.append('image', null);
      const res = await API.POST({
        url: '(serverurl)',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: You are stringifying the **requestBody**. You need to deserialize to the JSON object in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Hi are you using express? If you are you need to use cors to allow external connections to your server.